# Infragistics WebDataGrid not getting disabled in chrome

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, infragistics, disabled-control, webdatagrid

I am working on Infragistics 17.1, I want to disable the Infragistics WebDataGrid. So I used `webDataGrid.Enable = False` property.

This is working in Internet Explorer perfectly i.e. grid is in grey out and  disabled state, but in chrome view is not in disabled state.

I have some findings like, after rendering in HTML the webdatagrid element have attribute `disabled="disabled"`, because of this IE grid is looks in disabled state, but somehow its is not working for chrome.

Maybe somebody already faced this issue and have solution for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have workaround for this issue something like below with css changes.
`[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: grey;
}`

Not only for the WebDataGrid of Infragistics but for many other controls which having same problem this works. We can use more appropriate css selector to apply those properties to specify controls only.